# dtexec.exe without full SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-sql-database

I know that Azure SQL Database does not have SQL Server Agent to run SQL jobs. I can run the SSIS package through command prompt. I can create & run SSIS package through SSDT with no restriction but same package if I want to run on server through command line I need dtexec.exe. How same package runs with SSDT without SQL Server?

Can I have `dtexec.exe` without installing full version of SQL Server? I can't afford SQL Server license for Prod server.

Comment: dtexec isn't SSIS. It's only the command-line tool that sends commands to the SSIS subsystem. SSDT on the other hand is a development tool, it has nothing at all to do with SQL Server installations.

Comment: AFAIK SQL Azure doesn't support SSIS. Are you saying that you *can* execute `dtexec` on a SQL Azure instance? Or did you just mention `dtexec` as a command line tool? What are you *really* looking for? If it is how to do ETL in Azure, it's through Data Factory or Hadoop. You can't do it with SSIS

Comment: The real scenario is, we want to get rid of SQL server local instance and have the database on cloud (Azure SQL Database). We already have SSIS package which we modified for Azure SQL Database. But if we do not have SQL Server full installation we cannot run the SSIS package (as replied by steoleary). Is there any other option to run SSIS packages without full SQL Server? How SSDT can execute same package without SQL Server? Can we use that method to run it through command prompt or something?

Comment: SSIS **is** SQL Server, or rather, a part of it just like the database engine, OLAP or SSRS. SSDT *doesn't* execute something without SQL Server. You can view it, you can edit it, but you *can't* run it if the binaries aren't there. If that explanation isn't enough, consider that you you *did* find a way to *crack* SQL Azure and execute subsystem binaries that shouldn't be installed there in the first palce, it would be illegal - both for breaking the license and cracking the service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute SSIS packages using dtexec or any other method requires a full SQL Server license for the server that you are running them on.  Although SQL Server components can be split out, you still need a full license for every server you install them to.

Comment: Is there any other option to run SSIS packages without full SQL Server? How SSDT can execute same package without SQL Server? Can we use that method to run it through command prompt or something?

Comment: You can install the SSIS Server component on its own, but it still needs to be licensed with a SQL server license.

Comment: @steoleary Are you saying that, if I have one SQL Server and its license, I can use SSDT on different machine to process data, load to intermediate DB before loading to main SQL Server (for which I have license) ?